Accessing properties of a nested object in Typescript
I have a parent and child object as follows:
export interface ChildObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  quantity: number;
  rate: number;
  enabled: boolean;
}

export interface ParentObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | ChildObject;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  rate: number, 
  children1: ChildObject,
  children2: ChildObject, 
  children3: ChildObject
}

I am (naively) attempting to access the parameters of the child object:
    parent: {
      'name': 'parentName',
      'quantity': 1,
      'rate': 100,
      'children1': {}
    } as ParentObject,
    child: {
      'title': 'childName',
      'quantity': 1
    } as ChildObject

    modifyChildValues(index:string, quantity: number, direction: string) {
      this.parent[index]['quantity'] += quantity;
    },

Ideally this could be called with:
index = 'children1';
quantity = 1;
direction = 'increase';

modifyChildValues(index, quantity, direction)

This should result in the value of parent.children1.quantity being increased by 1.
I have tried typing various parameters without success. How can I dynamically access and modify the attributes of the child object via the parent object as shown?
The following works:
if (index == 'children1'){
        this.parent[index].quantity += quantity;
}

However, if I try without the if clause, I receive errors in VSCode:
Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'string | number | { [x: string]: string | number | boolean; id: number; title: string; quantity: number; rate: number; enabled: boolean; }'.

I tried a variety of solutions found on stackoverflow without much success. Example error messages include:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"quantity"' can't be used to index type 'string | number | { [x: string]: string | number | boolean; id: number; title: string; quantity: number; rate: number; enabled: boolean; }'

Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'string | number | { [x: string]: string | number | boolean; id: number; title: string; quantity: number; rate: number; enabled: boolean; }'.


Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now that code seems to be an excerpt of something or pseudocode and so I see lots of errors you're not asking about. If you make it easy for us to get started with a proper example it will be more likely you get a useful answer.

(see prev comment and pls make requested edits) Are you trying to restrict index to "children1" | "children2" | "children3"? Should it be dynamic and update automatically if ParentObject changes? Should it be dynamic and update automatically if the actual object changes? Right now I've got this playground link but I made some assumptions about what the [mre] looks like and what your goal is. If it's what you're looking for I could write an answer explaining (and help you with editing the question). If not, what's missing?

The reason is when you specify the property name children1, compiler knows its type as you have defined in following code...
export interface ParentObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | ChildObject;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  quantity: number;
  rate: number, 
  children1: ChildObject, // Here you have mentioned its type as ChidlObject Explicitly 
  children2: ChildObject, 
  children3: ChildObject 
}

but when you access it using index then compiler doesn't know at run-time which property it could be.
One way is you explicitly define the type as
(this.parent[index] as ChildObject)['quantity'] += quantity;


You could make the index parameter more strict
modifyChildValues(index: 'children1' | 'children2' | 'children3', quantity: number, direction: string) {
  this.parent[index]['quantity'] += quantity;
}

This means modifyChildValues will only accept those strings as the index and it knows that using those values to index parent will always result in a ChildObject.
However, with this solution those three strings are the only acceptable arguments. If you need to support calling the function with any string and not just a known key, then you can add a check inside the function to make sure you are accessing a ChildObject.
modifyChildValues(index: string, quantity: number, direction: string) {
  if (typeof this.parent[index] === 'object') {
    this.parent[index]['quantity'] += quantity;
  }
}

The definition [key: string]: string | number | ChildObject; means that a property for a string key can be a string, number or ChildObject. By adding the typeof check you can exclude the string or number possibilities and be sure that the property is a ChildObject.
